# How to view memory usage of containers after reboot?

Tags: logging, docker, memory, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have Docker containers running on my Ubuntu machine. Every so often (couple weeks) it becomes completely unresponsive. I suspect it's a memory leak issue with one of the containers. How can I view memory usage logs for the applications/containers *after* I reboot?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) a tool by google and it's on github